# is JSON schema validator working for PropretyNames?

Tags: java, json, jsp, json.net, jsonschema

i'm using Everit package for JSON schema validation. my use case here is i should allow only property key name as upper case, value can be anything. here is the code i used.

schema.json

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "schema",
  "description": "List of Config",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "propertyNames": {
      "pattern": "^[A-Z0-9_]*$"
    },
    "description": "List of Config",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "^[A-Z]": {
        "description": " Name",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "priority": {
            "description": "priority",
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "high",
              "medium",
              "low"
            ]
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "priority"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

product.json

```json
[
  {"TEST":{"priority":"medium"}},
  {"testing":{"priority":"medium"}}
]
```

Java Code :

```java
private boolean validateTemplateConfig(String emailTemplateConfig) {

        try {
            JSONObject jsonSchema = new JSONObject(
      new JSONTokener(JSONSchemaTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/schema.json")));
    JSONObject jsonSubject = new JSONObject(
      new JSONTokener(JSONSchemaTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/product.json")));

            Schema schema = SchemaLoader.load(jsonSchema);
            schema.validate(jsonSubject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
}
```

pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.everit.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.everit.json.schema</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

as per schema definition. program should have thrown error for key "testing" since it is a lower case letter. but instead im getting success response. could you please help here.

i tried this the same schema with another portal (https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/) . it is giving error.

could you please help here ? is there any problem with dependency. is this very old dependency ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the draft-04 version of the specification, and `propertyNames` was only added in draft 6. I don't know what version your implementation defaults to if `$schema` is not included, but you should try that first, or change your `$schema` to indicate a different version. The latest published version is `https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema`.

Comment: i tried schema 6 still am not seeing result.

Comment: can you please what version of dependency is should use ? currently am using 1.3.0

Comment: According to the GitHub Release history, draft 6 support was added at 1.6.0 https://github.com/everit-org/json-schema/releases/tag/1.6.0

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in @Ether's answer: use a version of JSON Schema that supports the keywords in use (namely "propertyNames" having been introduced in Draft 6) as well as version of the validator library supporting that JSON Schema version (mentioned in comments to the same answer).

In order to then evaluate the contents of the matching schema (i.e., under "TEST" in your example), you should:
replace `"properties": { "^[A-Z]": ...`
with `"patternProperties": { "^[A-Z]": ...`

Note: using `"patternProperties"` in combination with `"additionalProperties": false` would also be possible under JSON Schema Draft 4. No need for `"propertyNames"` then.

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
  "title": "schema",
  "description": "List of Config",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "propertyNames": {
      "pattern": "^[A-Z0-9_]*$"
    },
    "description": "List of Config",
    "type": "object",
    "patternProperties": {
      "^[A-Z]": {
        "description": " Name",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "priority": {
            "description": "priority",
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "high",
              "medium",
              "low"
            ]
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "priority"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```